# Add class to a element with an existing class

Tags: javascript

So is it possible with pure javascript to add a class to a element with an already existing class. I know you can add multiple classes simultanias to a element but my problem is like this:

```
if (i > 1) {
    elem.setAttribute("class", "mobile-hidden");
    elemGhost.setAttribute('class', 'mobile-hidden');
}

//This must be outside of if-statment becouse I am setting other attr on top
document.getElementById("myId").appendChild(elem); 

if (i < (myArray.lenght - 1)) {
    elemGhost.setAttribute('class', 'ghost');
    document.getElementById("myId").appendChild(elemGhost);
}
```

And as you can see in the second if-statment overrides the first for elemGhost.

This is the look I am after in the table (HTML DOM) I am creating. The classes are inside () in my visulat description below

> **CONTENT** ghost(*ghost*) **CONTNET** ghost(*ghost moblie-hidden*) **CONTENT(*mobile-hidden*)** and so on

Comment: Use `element.classList.add('classname')`

Comment: and certainly don't use `setAttribute` for `class` - if `classList` isn't available (on older browsers) use `element.className` directly

Comment: @Tushar - any reason why you decided not to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @Tushar and @Alniyak i found this.

For all browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").className += " anotherClass";
```

And for newer browsers lik exploere 10+ you can use this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
```

Thanks for the help guys!!